# Why the commutator of two elements is in the Cartan subalgebra?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, root-systems, semisimple-lie-algebras

I was reading Fulton and Harris' book when I found the following theorem:
[image]

[image]

In the proof of (ii) they say that $[X, Y] \in \mathfrak{h}$. Why is it true?

(It is an obvious corollary of this statement:

> If $X$ is an element of a positive root space and $Y$ is an element of a negative root space then $[X, Y]$ is in the Cartan subalgebra.

Do they mean that it's true?)

UPD: Before this they're proving special cases of the proposition I've claimed (for $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ and $\mathfrak{sl}_3$) without saying any words about the general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots, then $[\mathfrak g_\alpha,\mathfrak g_\beta]\subset\mathfrak g_{\alpha+\beta}$. In particular,$$[\mathfrak g_\alpha,\mathfrak g_{-\alpha}]\subset\mathfrak g_0=\mathfrak h.$$

Comment: But I thought that $X$ and $Y$ are in arbitrary eigenspaces -- an eigenvalue of $Y$ isn't necessarily opposite to an eigenvalue of $X$?

Comment: They were a bit sloppy here but, as they themselves claim, they are just adpating to a general semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ what they already done with $\mathfrak{sl}(3,\mathbb C)$. Take a look at the proof of **Claim 12.10** (pages 167–169).

Comment: Yes, I've read it. But the Claim 12.10 is proved in a very straightforward manner: they're just proving the proposition I claimed in my post for the special case of $\mathfrak{sl}_3$. I'm looking for an explanation of the general case.

Comment: All right. You want to prove that $X\cdot Y\cdot w\in W$. And you know that $X\in\mathfrak g_\alpha$ for some $\alpha\in R^+$ and that $Y\in\mathfrak g_\beta$ for some $\beta\in R^-$. If $\alpha+\beta=0$, you apply the method from the book. If $\alpha+\beta\in R^+$, you can apply the induction hypothesis; it imples that $[X,Y]\cdot w=0$. If $\alpha+\beta\in R^-$, then clearly $[X,Y]\cdot w\in W$, by the definition of $W$. In the remaining cases, $[X,Y]=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos - If $\alpha + \beta \in R^+$, why does the induction hypothesis (which is that $W_{n-1}$ is stabilized by elements of positive root spaces) imply that $[X,Y]\cdot w = 0$? It seems to me it only implies $[X,Y]\in W_{n-1}$. (Granted, this is enough for the purpose.)

Comment: (Perhaps you meant to separately consider the case that $\alpha+\beta$ is not a root, which does imply that $[X,Y]\cdot w = 0$?)